# How to center a div inside outer div horizontally, vertically and responsively

Tags: css

I am working [on this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/6sByJ/1/). How can I center the second div `#two` both horizontally and vertically? Can we have a set up to take care of the positions even in responsive mode or browser size changing?

I followed a trick from [CSS-Trick](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/exactly-center-an-imagediv-horizontally-and-vertically/) but it didn't work for me:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>

body {
    padding:25px;
}
#wrap {
    height:380px;
    width:60px;
    border:1px solid;

}
#two {
    height:300px;
    width:6px;
    background:#b2b2b2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -160px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need!

`#wrap` has been given `position: relative;`. This means any child elements of `#wrap` with `position: absolute;` will be positioned relative to it and not `body`.

The negative margins of `#two` need to be exactly half of the width and height of that div.

In regards to automatic sizing, this cannot be achieved with CSS alone using this method.

Have a fiddle - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/6sByJ/2/)

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap {
    position: relative;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border: solid 1px #CCC;
    overflow: hidden;

}

#two {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background:#b2b2b2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to responsiveness you must stay away from absolute positioning as much as possible and use percentages instead of fixed widths.

The rest is just good ol css

```
body {
   padding:25px;
}
#wrap {
   height:380px;
   width:100%;
   max-width:600px;
   border:1px solid;
   margin:0 auto;
   padding:25px;
 }
 #two {
   height:300px;
   width:100%;
   max-width:400px;
   background:#b2b2b2;
   margin: 0px auto
 }
```

Notice how the boxes actually decrease in size as you shrink the window

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6sByJ/4/)